# Get list column wise from a 2D Grid created via list comprehension

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have created a 2D grid using list comprehension which is list within a list as follows.

```
self.grid = [[0 for col in range(self.width)]
                     for row in range(self.height)]
```

The width and height acts as column and row value for the input list.

This is something I will use as 2D array and would like to access the whole list (elements) row wise and column wise with a single statement.

For the above shown grid I can iterate over the grid row wise processing each row at a time using a simple for loop as below.

```
for row in range(self.height):
                dummy_temp_line = list(self.grid[row])
```

I can now directly apply my required processing on the `dummy_temp_line` which is a `list`.

But I am facing difficult on how can do the same kind of processing column wise. Is there any way where I can get the elements for the grid in a list column wise.

**Note: Also the size of width and height will wary and will not always be same.**

Comment: actually I went ahead and used a simple 2D array traversal(column wise) method to finish my task but still want a better approach to so.

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose:

```
 data =  [[0 for col in range(self.width)]
                 for row in range(self.height)]


zipped = zip(*data)
```

Demo:

```
data =  [list(range(5))  for row in range(5)]

print(data)

print(list(zip(*data)))
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
```

If you want to update the original object self.grid:

```
self.grid[:] = map(list(zip*(whatever for sub in zip(*self.grid))))
```

As I mentioned in a comment you may find numpy useful, you can change the original array with:

```
data = np.array([range(5) for row in range(5)])

for col in data.transpose():
    col *= 10
print(data)
[[ 0 10 20 30 40]
[ 0 10 20 30 40]
 [ 0 10 20 30 40]
 [ 0 10 20 30 40]
 [ 0 10 20 30 40]]
```

You can perform calculations on all rows, certain rows, columns etc..

```
data *= 100

print(data)

data[:,1] += 50

print(data)

[[  0 100 200 300 400]
 [  0 100 200 300 400]
 [  0 100 200 300 400]
 [  0 100 200 300 400]
 [  0 100 200 300 400]]
[[  0 150 200 300 400]
 [  0 150 200 300 400]
 [  0 150 200 300 400]
 [  0 150 200 300 400]
 [  0 150 200 300 400]]
```

Comment: is this transpose a copy or modifies the original list

Comment: @Krishna_Oza, you are creating a new list. You might find numpy useful if you want a True 2d array

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution to transposing the entire grid is to use a list comprehension to produce an individual column as it is needed:

```
for column in range(self.width):
    dummy_temp_line = [self.grid[x][column] for x in range(self.height)]
```